# throwing exception for wrong array length

Tags: c#, arrays, exception

I'm trying to figure out how I can throw an exception based on the length of an array, but at the same time, be able to return a value if the length is correct

Ex:

```
 public Complex readInput()
 {
     Complex temp = 0;
     try
     {
          Console.Write("Enter input: ");
          string input = Console.ReadLine();

          String[] cplx= input.Split(' ');
          if (cplx.Length != x)
          {
               throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("INVALID INPUT ENTRY...");
          }

          temp = new Complex(Double.Parse(cplx[0]), Double.Parse(cplx[1]), ...);
     }
     catch (FormatException)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("INVALID INPUT ENTRY...");
     }
     return temp;
 } // end readInput
```

Ideally, I'd just want the if (opr.Length ...) and IndexOutOfRangeException.. I think I'm using the IndexOutOfRange incorrectly. Is there a way to throw the exception if the array length is not equal to x (can be whatever #), but if it is, return whatever is in it without the try/catch?

Edit: Figured out a part of it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20580118/2872988

Comment: what is x ? you need to define it ?!

Comment: x is just a number. You can input any number there, it shouldn't matter

Comment: your code won't just work, x should be assigned a value, then in your catch block, you can add many catch next to each other with many exception types.

Comment: try something like string Test = cplx[x]; then if the index doesn't exist you will get Index Out Of Range Exception which will be handled by Catch.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to throw by like this

```
 public Complex readInput()
 {
     Complex temp = 0;
     try
     {
          Console.Write("Enter input: ");
          string input = Console.ReadLine();

          String[] cplx= input.Split(' ');
          if (cplx.Length >= x)
          {
               throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("INVALID INPUT ENTRY...");
          }

          temp = new Complex(Double.Parse(cplx[0]), Double.Parse(cplx[1]), ...);
     }
     catch (FormatException)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("INVALID INPUT ENTRY...");
     }
     return temp;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Hy, the code will be a little better if you use your own exception description. Try using Exception(string description). The code will look a lot better of this way. Remember that the exception is to alert to the programmer that some thing is not working fine.

```
        Complex temp = null;
        try
        {
            Console.Write("Enter input: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            String[] cplx = input.Split(' ');
            if (cplx.Length != x)
                throw new Exception("INVALID INPUT ENTRY...");

            temp = new Complex(Double.Parse(cplx[0]), Double.Parse(cplx[1]));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("INVALID INPUT ENTRY...");
        }
```

Comment: According to MSDN, "Do not throw System.Exception, System.SystemException, System.NullReferenceException, or System.IndexOutOfRangeException intentionally from your own source code." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx